# JPA 2.0 Provider Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I have very strange problem we are using jpa 2.0 with hibernate annotations based 
Database generated through JPA DDL is true and MySQL as Database;

i will provide some reference classes and then my porblem.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Common implements serializable{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
 private Long id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn
 private Address address;
        //with all getter and setters
        //as well equal and hashCode

}

@Entity
public class Parent extends Common{
         private String name;
         @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy = "parent") 
         private List<Child> child;
         //setters and rest of class
}

@Entity
public class Child extends Common{
//some properties with getter/setters
}

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
 private Long id;

       private String street;
      //rest of class with get/setter

}
```

as in code you can see that parents and child classes extends Common class so both have address property and id , the problem occurs  when change the address refference in parent class it reflect same change in all child objects in list and if change address refference in child class then on merge it will change address refference of parent as well

i am not able to figure out is it is problem of jpa or hibernate

Comment: There is a little bit of mapping information missing here. Are you attempting to map inheritance or do you just what seperate PARENT table and CHILD tables with similar structure? Can you include the Class level annotations (@Entity etc) as you have them.

Comment: Removed references to Spring MVC, since it's not relevant, and confuses the issue.

Comment: thanks Davis yes i forgot to place these annotations,actually i am having separate table for parent and child with fields from inherited class common. the thing i can't figure out is why it change the reference of child->address in parent. when i just change reference of address for parent

Comment: @user558019: Can you show some sample code that changes these references?

Comment: axtavt. actually i have check in code there is nothing in code that changing reference. let me explain you some thing in detail. i have list of child object in parent class when i change address property of parent it also change the just id field of address property in child list in parent class.

Comment: right now i have done some debugging and found a strange behavior in application. when it loads one child object from parent list for update on start id for address property for rest all child in parent list are ok, but when update is submitted it changes id of address in all child list. actually when i remove child from sessionattributes list it lost id on every update. i don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed in code how this was happening, i.e. does this happen in just one persistence context?

Comment: I tried the described sequence of events across three persistence contexts, and it worked as expected. Can you show the SQL which Hibernate produces? Hibernate setting the address id on the wrong table is very, very unlikely.

Comment: This problem sounds like you have a problem with your entitymanager managed entities scope. Could you show how you use the entitymanager to do this (with code in the post as there is way to much info in the comments to this post).

Answer (score 1):

If you have shared instances of Address, changes made when it's in the "scope" of a child does affects the parent, because you are dealing with the same Address instance in the parent object.

For instance:

```
Parent1.address => Address #1
Child1.address => Address #2
Child2.address => Address #2
Child3.address => Address #1
```

In this case, if you change Child3.address.street, it means that it also changed Parent1.address.street. Note that what makes Address in Parent1 and Child3 the same is the ID. If they hold the same ID, they are the same instance (ie: "shared" among both objects).

Comment: partenon its not shared object parent has its own address and chlid object has its own address. so that objects are different not shared object, just place in common class beacuse of code management even i have placed address in difference class by removing common class and placing address property in parent and child.may be there some issue with EntityManager